# Need to use Focus in asp .net text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

in on blur() event i have used jquery for validation . If validation occurs the text box color should change and the cursor should be on the same text box .  I have used focus() for this , but it is not working. Can you help me on this ?

```
HTML CODE :

<asp:TextBox ID="txtMemoName" runat="server" Width="200px" onblur="alertevent();" ></asp:TextBox>



JQUERY :
function alertevent() {
        var value = $("#<%=txtMemoName.ClientID %>").val();
        if (value == "") {
     $("#<%=txtMemoName.ClientID %>").focus();
     $("#<%=txtMemoName.ClientID %>").css('border', '1px solid red');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

**HTML CODE :**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMemoName" runat="server" Width="200px" onblur="alertevent(this);" ></asp:TextBox>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
 function alertevent(elem) {
        var value = $(elem).val();
        if (value == "") {
     $(elem).focus();
     $(elem).css({border:'1px solid red',color: 'read !important'});
    }
}
```

OR try unobtrusive

```
$('input[id$=txtMemoName]').on('blur', function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == "") {
         $(this).focus();
         $(this).css({border:'1px solid red',color: 'read !important'});
        }
    });
```

Comment: i get color. now i want to focus textbox.

Comment: use the complete code...it will be give you focus in textbox.

Comment: No. it did not focus textbox.

Comment: i did. but textbox not focus

Comment: hey sorry guys. its working in IE and chrome. but not working in firefox. i want it work in all browser